# MMS in C# application

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to send MMS with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54092/how-to-send-mms-with-c)
>   [What kind of technologies are available for sending text messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019/what-kind-of-technologies-are-available-for-sending-text-messages)

Hi,

How to send MMS text message from a c# application? Is there free dll/tools available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number and the provider, you can send a text message using an e-mail address, and e-mail functionality is built into the .NET framework using System.Net.SmtpClient and related objects.

Comment: Many thanks, from SMTPClient object i know to send email, can i send email to mobile number from smtp client object?

Comment: You can not. It may not have occured to you, but email IS NOT SMS. What you need is a SMS Provider (that you have to pay).