# SMS + Web app: Providers of SMS "Long codes" for use by U.S. carrier subscribers within U.S.?

Tags: web-applications, sms, mobile-phones, cellular-network

Q.: How to get a cellular phone SMS "Long code" for use by U.S. carrier subscribers within U.S.?

Background: I'm building a web app that receives queries from/sends answers to cell phones. The app design (and business model) expects to communicate with cell devices via SMS, addressing the web app via an SMS "Long code" (VMN or MSISDN). The mobile phone subscribers will be sending/receiving within the U.S. and using U.S. carriers. Long codes are not available within the U.S. cellular services.

Comment: A long code enables you to basically have a number per subscriber right? Assuming your # is "4444" you could add a "11" etc. and would know who replied to you. Correct? Maybe you could add that definition. For example, I am only familiar with short codes in SMS lingo.

Comment: @Till; this is generally referred to as shortcode suffixing.  But it still requires your to purchase a shortcode.  Longcodes generally refer to full MSISDNs, i.e. in the US +1.123.555.5555.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task. First, you'll need to get a code. Then you have to negotiate with all the carriers to get them to recognize it.

Or you can use someone like Cell It (http://www.cellitmarketing.com/) which has handled all of these things and acts as an intermediary for you.

I have no relationship with them but we are exploring doing something similar and the expertise of negotiating with all of the carriers has us looking for someone to work with who does that.

Answer (score 1):

A 'long code' is just a normal phone number (full MSISDN in e.164 format)  You can get one by purchasing a SIM card (in the case of GSM -- you have to get the whole phone in CDMA today as they don't use SIM like identity modules yet).  Once you have that you can get a GSM modem and use standard COM programming for the modem to send and receive SMS messages.  Last I looked the cheapest carrier for this in the US was T-Mobile with an unlimited messaging plan.

As Barry pointed out you are not supposed to use this method for commercial purposes, but my experience working at an SMS aggregator was that a lot of people are doing it this way.  Check the fine print in the contract to make sure you know what 'unlimited' really means, also be mindful that the speed of a GSM modem is not so good for large scale operations.  For large commercial applications you may need to look at connecting to an aggregator.  But then you have to negotiate the solution with the aggregator and operator so you might not be able to use a long code.

Answer (score 1):

Group Texting is a new long code service (http://grouptexting.com). Unlike Twilio there are no charges for incoming messages and no 1 sms/second rules!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have answered your question in a different post.  You can see it here:

[What kind of technologies are available for sending text messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019/what-kind-of-technologies-are-available-for-sending-text-messages#53067)

Hopefully, it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The only legal way to get a "long code" in the US is to buy a Cell phone modem and a sim card.

Normally all traffic Server to Consumer in the US is done over short codes, which cost about $500/month.

And you are not suppose to use long codes for any commercial purposes

Comment: references would make this answer great.

Answer (score 0):

If your just going to send out text messages get kannel hook up a gsm phone to it and your done ..

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a short code to do any automated sms marketing.  This includes simply responding to queries about a product or event.  If you do not do this you can expect that carriers will eventually block your number.  Even if you do get a short code carriers can still block your number if you fail their audits.  Audits usually include providing a one response unsubscribe to your service and only sending messages to opted in customers.  There are a lot more guidelines and they very from carrier to carrier but most info can be found at the [MMA Site](http://www.mmaglobal.com/main)

Answer (score 0):

broadtexter.com uses a 10 digit long code (646-662-3101) which is registered to t-mobile they are able to send and receive SMS in the United States.

I've also just recently posted this: [BULK SMS, Long Codes (VMN MSIDN), T-mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090657/bulk-sms-long-codes-vmn-msidn-t-mobile)

In my experience the users on stackoverflow are more than willing to help a fellow developer so check that link soon as I'm sure it might help you out as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.twilio.com offers long codes for SMS.

Just two caveats:

1. They enforce a 1 sms/second rule (although they automatically queue messages if you go over the rate)
2. They charge 3 cents/message for **both** incoming and outgoing.