# BULK SMS, Long Codes (VMN MSIDN), T-mobile?

Tags: sms

Does any US wireless carrier offer individuals or companies with a direct connection to the SMSC?

The number is 747-772-3101 (repalce 7's with 6's)

This number is registered to t-mobile, also verified by t-mobile to be a valid subscriber sending 160,000+ text messages monthly and that all they have is an unlimited text messaging plan on top of the cheapest voice plan. This company of the number verified to me that they don't use gsm modems as they are too slow.

So I know it's possible but who would I contact, Sales or anyone else reachable through a 1-800 is ignorant to these services and developer.t-mobile is worthless and doesn't reply to emails.

Any info??

Answer (score 0):

Most likely they are connected to an Aggregator (Sybase 365, Mblox, Netsize, Verisign, etc.  Smaller guys like multimode and Clickatell are more open to this) that is connected to T-Mobile.  As they have chosen to not use a shortcode they simply buy a regular T-Mobile SIM/MSISDN and use the full longcode as the origination address of the messages.

A lot of companies use aggregators to enable Oracle Applications Server to send SMS messages.

Comment: @160k sms per month, they would be spending $77k a year at the aggregators .04/SMS fee. they have been free for over 3 years "$230k" they ARE NOT using an aggregator.

Comment: additionally they do not insert advertisements or monetize the service in any way and specifically targets a 0 income demographic and they don't have any investors or any such way of forking over that much money.

Comment: US$.04 is a published price, volume like you mention would entitle them to large discounts for a2p traffic, potentially down to fractions of a penny.  Maybe they are using the 'free' email to SMS gateway?  I think that still works on T-Mobile...?  Don't see how else they could be doing it.  SS7 is more expensive than the aggregators.

Answer (score 0):

does anybody have more info on this????

i did a little investigation and here is what i have determined.  the company that the long code is tied to is broadtexter.com.  they offer a free service to people who want to follow bands/comedians/acts/ etc.  you basically join their fan club.

when i text help to the phone number it immediately autoresponds from that same number.  that means they are either using an agg with a dedicated vmn (totally possible) of they are using a mobile modem with a sim (totally possible as well, and probably cheaper), but basically all they are doing from this phone number is pushing traffic to their website.

once you go to their website and sign up to a fan club; ALL FUTURE COMMUNICATION is mo/mt thru the SMTP gateway.  dead giveaway is that they ask for your carrier when you sign up.  second dead givaway is the caller id is xxxxxxx@broadtexter.com every time.

so the simple answer is that they are only using the vmn (long code) to drive people to their website to sign up...then all future communication is over SMTP.  so the 160K+ messages are occuring thru the SMTP gateway.  since they appear to be non-commercial (no ads, no spamming, etc.) and they are somewhat of a peer to peer setup, they probably fly under the radar (or are accepted by) the carriers.

if anyone can offer more insight to this, i would love to read it!

Comment: hey ken, smtp is possible, but you have to call the carrier directly and get whitelisted. for example, to get white listed from sprint, virgin, ntelos, helio and other sprint mvnos you have to call sprint and get your IP white listed, but I called t-mo and gave the rep that number and they told me they send thousands of texts from their account monthly i even got in touch with some other people at t-mobile about using a long code and working directly with the t-mobile smsc to send bulk sms but, eh long story, all i know is broadtexter has a direct deal with tmo, and tmo is being shisty with it

Answer (score 0):

I've got more info, and its kinda blowing my mind. I'm interested because I've got a social networking website and I'd like to set up an interactive SMS service without a shortcode. So I went to one of the profile pages on broadtexter.com and used their flash widget to join that bands club. I entered my mobile number and for provider I choose AT&T - option 1 (there were 3 options listed). Almost immediately I got a SMS asking me to reply with a Y to confirm. Here's the crazy thing: The number it was from was 1 (410) 000-001. At first I thought it was a regular cell number, then I realized it's missing a digit. Unless the area code is actually 141 and my iPhone is just formatting it weird. Except 141 isn't an area code?

Next, I replied with a Y and I got another text that asked me to reply with a photo for my profile (something that would be prefect for my site). This time the text from from 1 (410) 000-002.

So I sent back an MMS with a pic from my iPhone gallery, and I didn't get a reply yet. It's been about 15 minutes. It's kinda weird because to sign into their site, I need a username, which they never gave me. I haven't given them my email yet either. Anyway, I don't really care about that. I just wanna know what's going on with those numbers? How are they doing this?!

Comment: Hey Shaun, those 1410... numbers are special to AT&T. That's what they use for their email to sms gateway.  You can try it this way: send an email to xxxyyyzzzz@txt.att.net (replace xyz with your 10 digit phone number). You'll get an sms.  Reply to the sms, and you'll get it as an email.

MMS and SMS are not on the same gateway, so they won't forward accordingly.